Como adicionar caractere no final do input, enquanto o usuário digita?
O exercício em questão é calcular um desconto de 5% em qualquer produto, dai fiz o código abaixo.
preco = float(input('Digite o valor do produto: R$'))
desc = preco*0.05
print(f'\nSe o produto custa R${(preco):.2f} depois do desconto de R${(desc):.2f}(5%)'
      f' o produto custará R${(preco-desc):.2f}

Quero fazer um código onde digitaram a porcentagem há ser calculada, porém só consigo deixa o símbolo de % antes da entrada, quero que o símbolo % fique atrás do que é digitado
porc = float(input('Digite de quantos porcento é o desconto: %'))

Acredito que você não conseguirá fazer isso com o input. A biblioteca curses permite fazer isso.

Nativamente não é possível, o que você pode fazer é controlar a entrada com bibliotecas como getch(), que dependerá de escrever um wrapper próprio ou usar um existente. O uso dessa função será similar ao que faria em C/C++, ou qualquer outro wrapper de APIs nativas do sistema.

@Syzoth aliás, seria legal se aparecesse um exemplo de solução nativa, mas esbarra no problema de cada console ser de um jeito. Ultimamente o site anda cheio de código "lego" e nada de ensinar a lógica (falando das postagens em geral, não restrito a esse post). Se bem que o problema não é nem o site, a mentalidade da geração atual é de ir juntando coisa pronta sem domínio do fato.

Talvez a solução viesse de interceptar os fluxos stdin/stdout.

@AugustoVasques, isso que o AP que não vai dar certo ... removi a resposta .

@AugustoVasques infelizmente via sys.stdin não vai conseguir (admito que ando enferrujado, não sei se tem algum método nativo nas versões atuais). Se tratando de programar de fato, sem usar libs prontas de terceiros, provavelmente o OP só conseguirá faz como disse no meu primeiro comentário, usando getch() (por exemplo), usando msvcrt e/ou termios.

Não vai ficar TÃO BOM, o porcentagem não aparece enquanto não apertar o "ENTER". Dá para fazer substituir a linha no terminal
De: Digite de quantos porcento é o desconto:
Para: Digite de quantos porcento é o desconto: {porc} %
Se usar o [colorama][1], ele faz o Windows aceitar a entrada de ANSI escapes
O "\033[F" é um ANSI escape que move para o começo da linha anterior.
from colorama import just_fix_windows_console

just_fix_windows_console()

porc = float(input('Digite de quantos porcento é o desconto: '))
print(f"\033[F Digite de quantos porcento é o desconto: {porc} %")


Não é isso que o autor da pergunta pediu. O AP quer colocar o símbolo de % após digitar uma tecla no input e antes de digitar enter. Mais ou menos assim https://i.sstatic.net/rCv5YlkZ.gif , o autor dessa solução retirou sua resposta porque não tava tão boa.
